# How to set the tiles view in a document library as default

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, default, tiles

In SharePoint online i created a document library. In the new experience view you have the possibility to show the list with a tiles view.

is it possible to do it as a default view? If i make a view the tiles setting is not saved

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we have that feature yet to save tile view as default.

You can check the changes made to tile view and try to create similar custom view. That might help.

Comment: If is save a new view then it doesn't save that settings

Comment: Its not saving the view, we need to see what changes are made in UI when title view is selected. Similar scripting can be done through SharePoint designer. Basically it will be custom view, not OOTB.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a view (or editing one) you set the Style property to **Document Details**. As with every View, you can set this one as the default view.

[image]

Proof of concept (video): https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5K0Tsrp16dlVExzS3YwZl9EXzA/view

Comment: Sorry this isn't working. It will always show a list standard then tiles

Comment: I've set the other view as default, and it shows tiles forst when you click on the library from the start page...

Answer (score 0):

Use Format View works great and add this json:

```
{
"schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
"hideSelection": true,
"hideColumnHeader": true,
"rowFormatter": {
  "elmType": "a",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "ms-borderColor-neutralLight",
    "href": "[$FileRef]"
  },
  "style": {
    "float": "left"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "attributes": {
        "class": "ms-bgColor-themeLighterAlt ms-bgColor-themePrimary--hover ms-fontColor-white--hover"
      },
      "style": {
        "display": "flex",
        "flex-wrap": "wrap",
        "flex-direction": "column",
        "align-items": "stretch",
        "padding": "1px",
        "margin": "10px",
        "max-width": "930px",
        "box-shadow": "2px 2px 4px darkgrey"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "img",
          "attributes": {
            "src": "[$FileRef]"
          },
          "style": {
            "width": "200px",
            "height": "200px"
          },
          "children": [
            {
              "elmType": "span",
              "txtContent": "[$FileName]",
              "style": {
                "margin-bottom": "1px"
              },
              "attributes": {
                "class": "ms-fontSize-m ms-fontWeight-regular ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

}

Comment: "not a valid JSON"... This JSON is not accepted by SharePoint Online.

Comment: for some reason the last bracket came out of the code window, add ending bracket '}' when you copy the code

Answer (score 0):

Hi hikmatune and Julian Kulker,

I had a similar requirement in SharePoint Online Modern document library.
using Hikmatune's code with two changes I got something that is OK for what I need and may help others.
I added the missing } at the end of the code 
AND
removed the 200px height constraint which caused photos to stretch and look silly.

```
    {
"schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
"hideSelection": true,
"hideColumnHeader": true,
"rowFormatter": {
  "elmType": "a",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "ms-borderColor-neutralLight",
    "href": "[$FileRef]"
  },
  "style": {
    "float": "left"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "attributes": {
        "class": "ms-bgColor-themeLighterAlt ms-bgColor-themePrimary--hover ms-fontColor-white--hover"
      },
      "style": {
        "display": "flex",
        "flex-wrap": "wrap",
        "flex-direction": "column",
        "align-items": "stretch",
        "padding": "1px",
        "margin": "10px",
        "max-width": "930px",
        "box-shadow": "2px 2px 4px darkgrey"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "img",
          "attributes": {
            "src": "[$FileRef]"
          },
          "style": {
            "width": "200px"
          },
          "children": [
            {
              "elmType": "span",
              "txtContent": "[$FileName]",
              "style": {
                "margin-bottom": "1px"
              },
              "attributes": {
                "class": "ms-fontSize-m ms-fontWeight-regular ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
}
```

This works for what we require. A better solution would be to have Microsoft allow us to have a URL parameter to set "Tiled view" and or allow "Tiled View" be remembered / held by the default view chosen by the library owner.
Hope this helps others with this issue.
Dorje

Answer (score 0):

This now seems to be possible out of the box with SharePoint Online.

1. Create and populate a document library or open an existing library.
2. Change the view to tile view. You should now see an asterisk (*) next to the view name.
3. Click "Save current view" to update the view to tile view.

Tested in our tenant with a user who had previously worked on the library and another user who had not seen the library, yet. This worked for both use-cases. YMMV

(Sorry for necroposting. This is the post that Bing AI listed as a solution for this problem when I was researching.)