# Can i set the defualt view for my Document library inside modern experience to Tiles instead of List

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, list-view, modern-experience, tiles

I have added a new document library to my sharepoint online team site. and when i access the document library on Modern Experience, i will get this :-

[image]

which will render the documents using the List view. and i can change the List view to Tiles as follow:-

[image]

but my question is how i can set the defualt view for my document library to be Tiles instead of List? and if this can be achieved, then if i add this document library inside a modern page using the modern document library(preview) web part, will the document library get rendered in Tiles view inside the modern page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, we cannot set the "Tiles" as the default view of the modern library.

You can feedback to SharePoint UserVoice (https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/).

As a workaround, you can use a Picture library as a document library. It has Thumbnails view. Set the Thumbnails view as the default view. Add Document content type to the Picture library. And then use Embed to add the library to a modern page.

[image]

Comment: I think replacing all the document libraries to be Picture libraries just to get the Tiles view will not be the right decision. as i am sure there will be many options that we use to have inside the DL concerning documents that are not available inside the Picture libraries... for example as i remember, that the "one drive" client application can only sync document libraries... so we will lose this option...

Answer (score 2):

1) In your document library, click on the Tiles link and then again click on the `Save view as` which will open a popup.

Enter a name like `Tiles view` which will then appear as below:

[image]

Once it appears, you will also have the option to set it as default view as below:

[image]

Once you click this, the Tiled view will be the default view of the site.

2) No, it wont be set as the default view of the library webpart. If however, you want something like that, then you should use `Highlighted content` webpart and set the source as `A document library in this site` as below and in the layout section, keep it as Cards which will give a view similar to Tiles view.

Do note, the library webpart is still in preview.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply.. regarding your first point, if i set the titles as the default view will this be applied to all users? or this is a personal setting concerning the current user only? regarding the second point, i can not see the `Highlighted content` web-part inside our modern pages.. also if this is still in preview phases then i will not add it to our customer live site,, what do you think ??

Comment: 1) for all users 2) Not sure why , its standard OOTB webpart. 3) Preview webpart is ok, not great, adding it to live site would be ok as long as you inform your customers about it, if anything goes wrong you can blame MS :)

Comment: Doesn't work.  Tiles and List formats are separate from views and not linked.   If I do as you say, then go to "All Documents" view, and then select the "List" format, and then select the "Tiles" view, it still shows the view in the "List" format.  It doesn't go back to tiled.

Answer (score 0):

My experience yesterday with a modern list is that when designating a modern library with Tile as the default view is only at the personal view level, not public view.

Answer (score 0):

For those who want an OK solution to this using format JSON for SharePoint modern sites there is a solution that may work in some situations in this thread
[How to set the tiles view in a document library as default](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/197410/how-to-set-the-tiles-view-in-a-document-library-as-default)

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching for a workaround while we wait for Microsoft to make Tile Preview an option in the default view settings. I tried Picture Libraries and Highlighted Content, but they did not display the content as nicely as Document Libraries.

What I ended up doing was adding a "Thumbnail" column to the Document Library itself. To do this, I went to the library, clicked "+ Add Column", selected "Picture" and named the new column "Thumbnails". Now, it doesn't matter if the users in my organization are viewing the library in Tile or List mode—they will see the preview images regardless.

You can also rearrange or hide other columns in the library to get your view looking even cleaner.

Hope this helps!